# convert alpha/arm executable binary back to alpha/arm instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm, executable

for some research reasons, I would like to convert alpha/arm executable back to alpha/arm instructions. I am currently seeking any tool that can do this job easily.

Any possibilities? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What type of executable is it?

If it is ELF executable you can use objdump command from linux binutils package to get the assembly back.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/

Also you there is an [IDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Disassembler) tool from HexRays that covers a huge variety of architectures and executable formats.   The IDA tool is not free.

Comment: objdump can disassemble raw binaries too, not just ELF. E.g.: `objdump -b binary -m arm -D myfile.bin`.

Comment: @Vlad for example, my binary is Alpha/OSF4 (ecoff). I will try this

Comment: objdump should understand Alpha/ecoff so is IDA.  But, you need to get correct version of objdump.  Or you can just download the GNU binutils source and build cross-compile package for Alpha/Ecoff  (just use correct options for configure script)